# Finding location of a bitmap within another bitmap

Tags: c#, search, bitmap

I am writing a program that will screenshot the primary screen, convert to bitmap, then search the screenshotted bitmap with a bitmap "key" almost. It compares the bitmap "key" to the whole picture, finds where they match, moves cursor to location, then clicks the mouse. I am having trouble with `bmpLogin` being null.  I have my bitmap key in `Mopar/Mopar/Resources/bmpLogin.bmp`. I cannot seem to find this image to do the comparison. Here is relevant code.

Start Button:

```
    private void startBotButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Screenshot
        //This is where we will be writing the loop for the bot
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Screenshot();

        //Set the background of the form the screenshot that was taken
        this.BackgroundImage = bmpScreenshot;
        //Find the node and check if it exists within the screenshot
        Point location;
        bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.bmpLogin, bmpScreenshot, out location);

        //Check if it found the node in the bitmap
        if (success == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find the node");
            return;
        }

        //Move the mouse to the node
        Cursor.Position = location;

        //click
        MouseClick();
    }
```

Screenshot:

```
    //Screenshot the screen
    private Bitmap Screenshot()
    {
        //This is where we will store the screenshot
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        //Create a graphics object so we can draw the screen in the bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        //Copy from screen to bitmap
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);

        //Return the screenshot
        return bmpScreenshot;
    }
```

Searching the bitmap:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find the location of a bitmap within another bitmap and return if it was successfully found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmpNeedle">The image we want to find</param>
    /// <param name="bmpHaystack">Where we want to search for the image</param>
    /// <param name="location">Where we found the image</param>
    /// <returns>If the bmpNeedle was found successfully</returns>
    private bool FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
    {
        if (bmpNeedle == null || bmpHaystack == null)
        {
            location = new Point();
            return false;
        }
        for (int outerX = 0; outerX < bmpHaystack.Width - bmpNeedle.Width; outerX++)
        {
            for (int outerY = 0; outerY < bmpHaystack.Height - bmpNeedle.Height; outerY++)
            {
                for (int innerX = 0; innerX < bmpNeedle.Width; innerX++)
                {
                    for (int innerY = 0; innerY < bmpNeedle.Height; innerY++)
                    {
                        Color cNeedle = bmpNeedle.GetPixel(innerX, innerY);
                        Color cHaystack = bmpHaystack.GetPixel(innerX + outerX, innerY + outerY);

                        if (cNeedle.R != cHaystack.R || cNeedle.G != cHaystack.G || cNeedle.B != cHaystack.B)
                        {
                            goto notFound;
                        }
                    }
                }
                location = new Point(outerX, outerY);
                return true;
            notFound:
                continue;
            }
        }
        location = Point.Empty;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly *GetPixel* is tooooo slow. *Lock-Unlock* your bitmaps. Secondly what @DevNull says.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid my rep is too low to just comment.  So apologies for the non-complete answer

You don't quite give enough to answer more definitively (we'd need to see how your resource is included in the project) ... however here is a good answer on the various rootcauses for your problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a4ace5de-9376-44d0-a453-1f1c39c47a86/where-did-the-propertiesresources-go?forum=csharpgeneral

To improve readability (and to prevent a goto), I would consider moving the inner two loops into a function.

Lastly (and possibly most importantly), for performance, you always want to iterate over y on the outer loop, and x on the inner loop.  You should notice a considerable speedup on images of any significant size.